# Disabling swipe right to previous page on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, touch

I'm trying to use http://wipetouch.codeplex.com/ to implement swiping on a Meteor app to shift between templates in Iron Router.

It works beautifully on iOS and Android but on Windows Phone, the OS' native swipe gesture (swiping right in the browser moves one page back in history) interferes with the user's swiping action.

Is there any way I can disable this?

Also which other platforms have similar functionality which would prevent the user from swiping in the web app effectively?

*As an example, [this](http://todos.meteor.com) app also uses the same library to implement swipe gestures.*

Note: Using touch-action: none on the body tag does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered the same problem on a little web application : it which was a scratch game, where the player had to swipe the finger all over the "scratchable" zone to discover what he had won.

The game was supposed to run on Windows 8.1 tablets, with IE10 on it.

We put in the css this snippet :

```
*{
    touch-action: none;
}
```

The result is to completely deactivate any touch events on the app (including the swipe backward / forward).

But we had to reactivate the touch event only on the scratch zone, to allow the player to play :)

For this we had to add this :

```
#playzone{
    touch-action: chained;
}
```

The app still works perfectly, both on IE10 on tablets but also on Windows Phone 8.1.

(please forgive my English, it's not my mother tongue)

EDIT : After having tested more on IE, it seems that adding the `touch-action:none;` on the html element is enough to achieve what the OP wanted.

Comment: This does not work. Using `touch-action: none;` and adding in even the `touch-action: chained;` does not prevent the browser's swiping backward in history feature. That is what I'm trying to disable. Read the question more carefully.

Comment: As I said, on our app the code I gave you was enough to prevent the swiping back in history. I Just tested it again an it works flawlessly. Maybe we'll ne able to help you more if You give us the code that doesn't work

Comment: Could you link to your app or a subset of it in a bin online?

Comment: I did a pen for you : http://codepen.io/benjaminchanudet/pen/mybGYV?editors=110
Turns out the `-ms-touch-action : none;` is enough on the html element.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much! You just made my day. Don't know what I was doing wrong. I tried this first before anything else and it didn't seem to work. Nonetheless, approve my edit. It works without the prefix.

Comment: What is `chained`? Don't find this in [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx). And why you do not use `pan-x/pan-y` ?

Comment: The project where I used this snippet dates back to January. When I looked for solutions I found the `-ms-touch-action` code on a microsoft blog. Since then the docs changed and `chained` must fallback to another property, I think.

Comment: But it seems, as my Pen showed, that `-ms-touch-action:chained;` isn't even needed now. `touch-action:none;` on the html element is enough to disable the swiping back in history feature of IE.

Comment: It doesn't work on win phone 8.1. touch-action: chained is not a valid option at all and touch-action: none; itself just disables all scroll actions on the whole application. Is there a working solution?