# JQuery Mobile Swipe events on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, windows-phone, swipe

I'm using JQuery Mobile for recognizing swipe events and it works well. Events fire on Windows Mobile (7.5 in my case), but what also fires is the web browser's default events for navigating the browsing history. Swiping right turns back a page. How can I prevent this default behavior?

I tried the preventDefault() and it didn't help here.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764045/disabling-swipe-right-to-previous-page-on-windows-phone ?

Comment: Well, this works really well. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't see it before, but it causes me another problem. I can not scroll the main content with touch events. Event when `touch-action: pan-y` assigned to body's style.

Comment: But on the second thought I can just use `touch-action: pan-y` on body only. Not prevent all touches and then readd them. It solves my problem, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will deactivate the touch:-

**Add CSS snippets:**

```
*{
    touch-action: none;
}
```

But to reactivate the touch event only on the some zone, to allow the player to play or active the touch

To activate for certain places add this :-

```
#activetouch{
    touch-action: chained;
}
```

Reference:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Comment: While the `chained` attribute didn't work for me, the `none` solved my original problem. Also on WP7.5. This is my answer. Also @halfzebra comment was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 7/IE9 does not support mousemove event so there is not way for jquery mobile to recognize swipe event.

Some mobile frameworks like [Apache Cordova (PhoneGap)](http://phonegap.com/) provide workaround for this by adding special shim between native (silverlight) touch events and web browser control to fix missing mouse events. [Demo](http://www.risingj.com/archives/209)

This works fine on Windows Phone 8 since it supports mousemove.